# Using a static class inside CakePHP application

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, static-classes, vendor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instantiating a vendor class in class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960938/instantiating-a-vendor-class-in-class-constructor)

I have a 3rd party vendor class called **fancyVendor** and I load it inside my controller with this:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'fancyVendor', array('file' => 'fancyVendor.php'));
class MyController extends AppController {

}
```

But I need to reach this vendor class from other controllers. It seems like I need to use this as a static class. How can I use a vendor class statically ?

Comment: Please verify - you mean you need to reach the Controller class from other controllers?

Comment: Sorry. I need to reach vendor class from controllers.

Comment: is this your custom file? or a third party product?